# android fragment not restoring properly

Tags: android, fragment, restore

My Fragment sometimes is not properly restored. It happens when app is no more in background cached process and then re-opened. When it happens all that is written in `onActivityCreated` is not happening however my `System.out.println();` is called. So i end up my items are no clickable anymore. How should i fix that ?

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onActivityCreated");

    relative1 = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.r1);
    relative2 = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.r2);
    relative3 = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.r3);
    relative4 = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.r4);

    relative1.setOnClickListener(this);
    relative2.setOnClickListener(this);
    relative3.setOnClickListener(this);
    relative4.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Comment: its hard to say whats going on without seeing more of your fragment code. Just curious why you are obtaining your views from onActivityCreated vs onViewCreated or onCreateView methods?

Answer (score 0):

When you send your app to background and then foreground, if there is a memory problem or "Do Not Keep Acitivities" is ticked, this will be happen. Your activity and fragment will be created again. 
In your situation, if you keep for a long time at background, it will be probably recreated. When this happens, Activity will keep a sign of the opened fragments and will open them again. If you do not kontrol the and that fragment will be opening on Activity's onCreate and also Activity will open with its sign. 
You can fix this, if you control your fragment is opened or not by a flag. If it's already created, you should not open a second.. one.